# Statement executeQuery exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I can't figure out why the executeQuery method is throwing an exception, I tried running statement on mysql and it works correctly.

Here is the code:

```
        queryInserimento = "INSERT INTO operatore (Cognome, Email, Nome, Sede, Telefono, Username,Password) "
                + "VALUES ('" + cognome + "','" + email + "','" + nome + "','" + sede + "','" + telefono + "','" + username + "','"+cryptedPassword+"');";
        System.out.println(queryInserimento);
        try {
            Connection conn=MySQLDaoFactory.initConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement=conn.prepareStatement(queryInserimento);
            try {
                statement.executeUpdate() //Here is the problem
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new ExecuteQueryException();  //throws this...
            }
```

Here is the trace:

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at business.BusinessDelegate.handleRequest(BusinessDelegate.java:35)
>       at presentation.command.InserisciOperatore.Execute(InserisciOperatore.java:25)
>       at presentation.ApplicationController.handleRequest(ApplicationController.java:183)
>       at presentation.FrontController.handleRequest(FrontController.java:35)
>       at presentation.ui.controller.NuovoOpController.conferma(NuovoOpController.java:85)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: dao.mySQL.ExecuteQueryException
>       at dao.mySQL.MySQLOperatoreDAO.inserisciOperatore(MySQLOperatoreDAO.java:54)
>       at business.entity.OperatoreBusiness.inserisciOperatore(OperatoreBusiness.java:48)
>       at business.GestisciOperatore.inserisciOperatore(GestisciOperatore.java:58)
>       ... 67 more

Comment: print the stack trace

Comment: `statement.executeUpdate()==1` What does this do ?

Comment: sorry, forget the "==1"

Comment: Should not the above code be as int count =  statement.executeUpdate(); In the second part you can check if (count >0) then the db was successfully update

Comment: Do you still have the problem?

Comment: Yes i still got the problem

Comment: Could you please show the output of `System.out.println(queryInserimento);`?

Comment: `code`INSERT INTO operatore (Cognome, Email, Nome, Sede, Telefono, Username,Password) VALUES ('a','a','a','Milano','a','a','0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661');`code`

This works manually on phpmyadmin

Comment: did you copy paste the output of the `System.out.println(queryInserimento);` statement?

Comment: What is `InserisciOperatore.java:25` and `BusinessDelegate.java:35` line?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if `statement.executeUpdate()` is 1 you need to put it in `if` statement.

```
try {
    if (statement.executeUpdate() == 1) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
        // do something else
    }
}
catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new ExecuteQueryException();  //throws this...
}
```

Comment: sorry, forget the "==1"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was a wrong type error.